# Creating a NSURL from an NSURL instance variable - invalid pointer

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsurl

I have an object that defines a property as an `NSURL`:

```
@interface fcpElement : NSObject
@property (copy) NSString* elementName;
@property (copy) NSURL* elementPath;
@property (copy) NSURL* elementParent;
@property () BOOL elementIsHidden;
@property (copy) NSString* elementType;

-(id)initWithName : (NSString*) elementName path: (NSURL*) elementPath parent: (NSURL*) elementParent hiddenValue: (BOOL) elementIsHidden type: (NSString*) elementType;

@end
```

In my app controller I create an `NSMutableArray` and populate it with my objects using my `init…` method.
I then have a button which calls a method on the app controller which creates a new `NSURL` by calling the instance variable from an object in the array, as follows:

```
for(currentElement in _finalCutData) {
    NSURL *currentElementPath = [currentElement elementPath];
```

Eventually I am wanting to do a comparison to see if this new URL is equal to another, but I always get errors that stop my program if I do anything like the following:

```
NSURL *currentElementPathAbsolute = [currentElementPath absoluteURL];
```

with the error: -[__NSCFString absoluteURL]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

If I add a breakpoint it says that `currentElementPath` is an invalid pointer. But if I `NSLog` `[currentElement elementPath]` I get the URL contained within.

How do I get the URL from my instance variable such that I can use it? Am I using the wrong parameter types in my property declarations? Or is it something else?

Comment: Apparently `currentElementPath` is an `NSString`, not an `NSURL`.  What does the `elementPath` method do? I don't see it in the docs - is it something you wrote?

Comment: “If I add a breakpoint it says that currentElementPath is an invalid pointer.” Where did you set the breakpoint? If you set it on the line that declares `currentElementPath`, then its initialization hasn't happened yet, so you'd need to step once (i.e., “do this line”) before the variable will have a value for you to print. The alternative is to set the breakpoint any subsequent line in the method; I would set it on the very next line.

Comment: The generic answer would be to run your app under Instruments with its Zombies template and see what killed off the URL before you tried to send it an `absoluteURL` message. More specifically, I think it's something in between those two points, namely `currentElementPath`'s declaration and the `absoluteURL` message, that you didn't show. Please edit your question to include all of the code between the declaration of `currentElementPath` and the use of it in the `absoluteURL` message.

Comment: I have updated my code which had some how omitted the rest of the property declarations in my object, in case that helps. @PeterHosey the absoluteURL declaration is the next line of code after my retrieval of the instance variable, it was all in one line of code inital but i split it into 2 to try and work out where the problem was.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is most likely that this call:

```
[currentElement elementPath];
```

is returning a string, not a URL. How is `-elementPath` implemented? Are you seeing any compiler warnings?

I assume `-elementPath` is implemented to be a simple getter method (perhaps as an `@property`). In which case, the fault lies in whatever code is storing that value in the first place.

Are you using ARC or manual memory management? If the latter, there's also a chance you've got a zombie here. You're not retaining the URL, and so it's being deallocated, and later replaced with a string.

Comment: elementPath is as you say a simple getter method as an @property (as listed in the fcpElement object in my code above. The objects in my array are getting their values from the following code:`NSURL *filePath;
        [currentFile getResourceValue:&filePath forKey:NSURLPathKey error:NULL];` current file being the current object in an enumerator. I am using ARC

Comment: @NicholasWarren: The value of `NSURLPathKey` is a path (which is a string), not a URL. If you want a URL, you already have one—that's what `currentFile` is. If you want a path (which you generally should not), you need to expect a string and handle it as such.

Comment: @PeterHosey Thanks very much - that was the solution. Now works as I expected.

Answer (score 0):

I'm surprised it seems I can help on this forum, since I'm a bit of a beginner, but the NSURL class has initialization methods that you should use, like initFileURLWithPath: You probably shouldn't override the NSURL initialization methods.

Comment: Where is the questioner “overrid[ing] the NSURL initialization methods”?

Comment: I'm not overiding the initialisation methods, just can't seem to get hold of the NSURL that I have as a property inside my object without it causiing errors, unless i'm nsloging it.

Comment: I apologize, I had thought your class was NSURL. The answer is essentially the same, that you are not properly initializing your NSURL object.